# Error when publishing after Visual Studio Update 2 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Ever since installing Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 2, I am unable to publish to any target at all.  I repeatedly get informed:

"Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DotNet.Internal - The system cannot find the file specified."

[image: Visual Studio Publishing Error]

Has anyone experienced the same issue and managed to resolve it?

Comment: Possibly related to later http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255393/unable-to-publish-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a while back, but I ended up wiping and reinstalling :(.