# Unable to publish in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, publish

Ever since installing Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3,

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

I am unable to publish to any target at all. I repeatedly get informed:

> Could not load file or assembly 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DotNet.Internal - The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and managed to resolve it?

I have repaired Visual Studio: No Success
I have reinstalled Visual Studio after deleting all files according to [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/435656ba-49df-4af4-b501-27b568fdeae1/unable-to-publish-to-any-target?forum=visualstudiogeneral), with no success

I have ensured that all updates have been applied to Visual Studio: No Success

Can someone please help me?

Asked in thread below is the installed version of -net and I have not installed anything besides windows  10 and visual studio 15. [image]

Comment: Are you able to provide us with the version of `.Net` you have installed on this system?

Comment: in the target framwork on properties of the project I can selected up to 4.6.1 but i have currently selected 4.5.2

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, hopefully someone has a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by reinstalling/repairing DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

Looking at a previous answer, I would guess that both the Azure SDK and the dotnetcore tooling previews both update the publish wizard components.

Comment: My error was that it could not install 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.DotNet.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0' :  updating "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" from Control Panel | Programs and Features fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by re-installing Azure SDK Tools from here:   [azure downloads](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/)